# How to make div push down everything below

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

So my question is how do I make a div push down everything that comes after it, even if the elements that come after have a fixed positions.

Let me explain the scenario:

I have the following structure:

```
<body>
   <div class="top_menu">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
   </div>
</body>
```

Where `.top_menu` has a `position:fixed;` and `top:0;`

Now using JavaScript I insert a new div right after `<body>` and wrap the rest in another div to end up with something that looks like this.

```
<body>
   <div id="notice_bar">
   </div>
   <div id="wrap">
      <div class="top_menu">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Now is there a way to make the `#notice_bar` div always push down the `#wrap` div with all its content?

Changing the `position:fixed;` attribute of `.top_menu` is not an option because this script I’m working on should work on any given website.

I’m really running out of ideas here so any tips will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the specific scenario were I'm working on right now in case anyone feels generous enough to play arroudn with it :) http://mirlostudio.com/choeducators

Comment: Maybe using `display: block` for the `#notice_bar` div?

Comment: Inserting your own code/HTML elements into other websites, and expecting everything to work without problems is a little to high of an aspiration – the diversity of layouts out there is simply to big for that. You could of course go through the “host” page in your script, try and identify all (or certain) fixed elements, and manipulate their coordinates – but that is still very likely to break stuff on any number of sites (especially so, if they use their own scripts that handle positioning dynamically.)

Comment: Probably best if you just offer people options to customize how and where the elements your script inserts should show up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the notice bar to remain at the top, while the menu scrolls with the page you could use a little jQuery/javascript to toggle a class that adds fixed positioning to the menu:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/kfjndtok/1/)**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.top_menu').toggleClass('scrolling', $(window).scrollTop() > $('#wrap').offset().top);
});
```

```css
.top_menu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background: grey;
}
.scrolling {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notice_bar">Notice Bar</div>
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="top_menu">Top Menu</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @apaul34208. Thank you very much for your example. Although this probably works the issue is that modifying the .top_menu element is not an option as the script I'm working on should work on any given website, not just the one in the example.

Comment: @GuillermoCarone what do you mean by "any given website"? The script will work for any website with similar markup, provided that you adjust the class/id names.

Comment: Are you looking for a pure css approach? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/kfjndtok/2/

Comment: @aoayk34208 I mean its a WP plugin I'm working on, so it should work on any website were the plugin gets installed. Your example gave me a few ideas to keep playing with. Thanks! :)

Comment: @GuillermoCarone Ah I see, that should probably have been in the question. In that case you may be better off with a Wordpress specific, php based solution. WordPress offers some hooks/API functions that may make your life a little easier.

Comment: Sorry I didnt specify... I did look for a WP hook but there doesent seem to be one that will do the trick... I'll keep looking into it and post if I find a solution. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @GuillermoCarone This may help: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

If you set the .wrap container to `position: relative;` - all elements inside the .wrap container that are absolutely positioned will be moved together with their parent container.

Comment: Thanks Christian. The thing is there are elements inside #wrap with position:fixed; and those do not seem to care about the #wrap relative position...